# Python Linked List, Unsure what is causing this error

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

I am trying to create a linked list but unsure on how i am getting this error:
Edited Code and Error Trace:

line 61, in module
    llist.output()

line 56, in output 
    llist.delete("Alabama")

line 50, in delete
previous_node.pointer = current_node.pointer

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pointer'

Here is my code:

```
class linkedlist:
    data = None
    class node:        
        data = None    
    start = None
    pointer = None
    def add(self, item):
            #check memory overflow
            try:
                new_node = linkedlist.node()
                new_node.data = item
                current_node = self.start
                #list is empty
                if current_node == None:
                    new_node.pointer = None
                    self.start = new_node
                else:
                    #item becomes the new start item
                    if item > current_node.data:
                        self.start = new_node
                        new_node.pointer = current_node
                    else:
                        #Find correct position in the list
                        while current_node != None and current_node.data < item:
                            previous_node = current_node
                            current_node = current_node.pointer               
                        new_node.pointer = previous_node.pointer
                        previous_node.pointer = new_node
                return True
                return self               
            except:
                return False        
    def delete(self,item) :
                current_node = self.start
                if current_node == None:
                    print("list is empty")
                    return False                
                #check the list is not empty
                if current_node != None:
                    #item is the start node
                    if item == current_node.data:
                        self.start = current_node.pointer
                    else:
                        #Find item in the list
                        while current_node != None and item != current_node.data:
                            previous_node = current_node
                            current_node = previous_node.pointer
                        previous_node.pointer = current_node.pointer                
    def output(self) :
        items = ["Florida", "Georgia","Delaware","Alabama","California"]
        for index in range(0, len(items)):
            llist.add(items[index])
        llist.delete("Alabama")
        for index in range(0, len(items)):
            print(items[index])                
llist = linkedlist()            
llist.output()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 47 you are using the variable `previous_node` without declaring it first. You declare one called `previous`, so I assume you meant to name that one `previous_node`:

```py
while current_node != None and item != current_node.data: 
    # this line used to say
    # previous = current_node
    previous_node = current_node               
    current_node = previous_node.pointer     
    previous_node.pointer = current_node.pointer
```

Edit:
Also, I think this line is wrong in your delete function:

```py
current_node = self
```

You're assigning the current_node to the entire list. What you probably meant to do is `current_node = self.start`

Edit #2:
A word of advice, when you get an error, read what it says and try to interpret it and figure out what it's trying to tell you.

Here's your error:

```
line 61, in module llist.output()

line 56, in output llist.delete("Alabama")

line 50, in delete previous_node.pointer = current_node.pointer

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pointer'
```

This is called a stacktrace. It's showing what functions were on the stack when the error occurred. You called `lllist.output()`, and within that function you called `llist.delete('Alabama')`, and within the delete function you got the error on line 50, the line that says `previous_node.pointer = current_node.pointer`.

It says `'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'pointer'.` That means that either `previous_node` or `current_node` is `None` in line 50.

The problem here is your break out of your loop as soon as `current_node` is `None`.

What you should do is check if `current_node` is `None` after you break out of your while loop. If that's the case, you haven't found the item you're trying to delete (it's not in the list).

Again, when you get an error, try to figure out what it's trying to tell you. That's what debugging is: stepping through your code and finding the cause of the problem, then fixing it. I've already helped you with three or four different errors, which is great! But you're smart and you know your code better than I do. Sometimes taking everything immediately to Stack Overflow isn't the best way to learn.

I hope this is helpful. I'm not trying to get preachy, I'm just letting you know that you can get good at debugging your own code by actually reading the error messages.

Comment: line 46, in delete
    current_node = previous_node.pointer
AttributeError: 'linkedlist' object has no attribute 'pointer'

Comment: sounds like the node is set to `None` and you're calling `node.pointer`. You should check if the node is `None` beforehand.

Comment: Will you edit your question with the entire error stacktrace, as well as your current updated code?

Answer (score 0):

When you get to this line:

```
previous_node.pointer = new_node
```

Python doesnt know what "previous_node" is because you never defined it.
My guess would be that this never gets executed:

```
while current_node != None and current_node.data < item:
  previous_node = current_node
```